# rails 3 doesn't render format xml for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so i'm trying to send xml back from my controller..

```
render xml: ['hello world']
```

correctly gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<strings type="array">
  <string>hello world</string>
</strings>
```

however

```
render xml: 'hello world'
```

gives xml headers but the body is just:

```
hello world
```

which is not xml format.

bug?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Every XML document needs a root element, and I don't string is a valid option for a root.

Comment: I think you can just do something like `render xml: "<response>string content</response>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API documentation:

> When a request comes in, for example for an XML response, three steps
>   happen:
>
> 1) the responder searches for a template at people/index.xml;
>
> 2) if the template is not available, it will invoke
>   `#to_xml` on the given resource;
>
> 3) if the responder does not `respond_to :to_xml`, call
>   `#to_format` on it.

See:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html

In Rails, Arrays respond to to_xml but Strings do not.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. What's best practice here then? All xml responses should be wrapped in an arbitrary root as ismaelga suggested?

Though I'm still not convinced this is expected behavior.. <string>hello world</string> sounds like very valid xml to me

Comment: What if you're doing some simple ajax and you just want to return a string to the DOM. Does convention really state that I should write a new partial file and render the partial?